# Create a button in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to use these picture as a corner for a button. The buttons name is Test with background "#F1F2F2"

How should I create by using CSS?

Please remember that the css code need to adapt to older web browser.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to be specific about which browsers and how old.

Comment: Don't just ask for code... Take a look at `background-image` and `background-position`, and ask about what problems you are facing with your solution.

Comment: And CCS alone cannot create anything. It needs to be attached to some HTML element, so you should tell us something about the element it will be styling as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use css? Border radius would be half the size of the parent element and is supported by IE 9 and above.

```
<span>hello</span>
span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbwL117m/

Otherwise do something like the code below and apply the appropriate css styles.

```
<span>
    <span class="left-image">image here</span>
    <span>Text</span>
    <span class="right-image>image here</span>
</span>
```